# python-docx adding return key symbols in find and replace if specified new line

Tags: python-3.x, ms-word, newline, python-docx, paragraph

My Code:-

```
from docx import Document



#open the document
doc=Document('teest.docx')


Dictionary = {
"number one ":"",
"number two ":"\n\n",
"number three ":"\n\n",
"number four ":"\n\n",

}

for i in Dictionary:
    for p in doc.paragraphs:
        if p.text.find(i)>=0:
            p.text=p.text.replace(i,Dictionary[i])
            p.alignment = 3

for para in doc.paragraphs:
    para.alignment = 3


#save changed document
doc.save('./test.docx')
```

Word document before running the code:-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfxWR.png)

Word document after running the code :-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NE7Zf.png)

any method to avoid the return key symbols ?

Comment: The "return key" symbols are line breaks and are inserted to replace any `"\n"` characters in the assigned text https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#docx.text.paragraph.Paragraph.text. You will need to place the separated text into distinct paragraphs to get the result you're after.

Comment: But Where should i use the ParagraphFormat objects in the python code ?

Comment: A replacement of the type you're asking for will make two or more paragraphs out of one original paragraph, basically a new paragraph for every `"\n"` character in the replacement string. You can use `Paragraph.insert_paragraph_before()` https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#docx.text.paragraph.Paragraph.insert_paragraph_before to add new paragraphs. You'll just need some fancy code to work out what text ends up in the current paragraph and what goes in each new paragraph.

Comment: Should i use Paragraph.insert_paragraph_before() in the dictionary itself ?

Comment: No. Use it on the paragraph that is getting the replacement. See answer below.

Comment: When i run the code, the paragraphs are getting Created before the word ! I don't want it like that ! i want the word to be erased and in the place of word the paragraphs  should be created !

Comment: @scanny Why did you remove Your Answer ?